# PC not waking up from Sleep / Hibernate on scheduled task

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

My `Intel NUC PC BIOS` supports wake up on `RTC`. I have enabled those options on BIOS.

On my `Windows 10 v.1809`, I create a scheduled task to wake up my system. The option to wake up the PC is explicitly checked - PC is always on AC power. Task is set to repeat every day at a specific time. Task is set to run whether a user is logged in or not (also tried with and without highest privileges).

Saving this task shows the task in the task list.

Doing `Powercfg /wakeuptimers` shows my task among `wakeuptimers` configured for the device.

Wake up timers are also enabled in Power management options.

I see some bizarre behaviour - upon entering `Hibernate`, the system definitely does not wake up as it's supposed to at the scheduled hour. For some reason, normal wake up doen't work either, clicking the power button doesn't do anything, it just stays asleep, based on the blinking light. Only way to is to `reboot` the system. This wasn't the case when I hadn't configured such a task - the system would wake up on the power button.

Also, when the PC is rebooted, the scheduled task disappears from task scheduler - it's almost as if the task was never created.`Wakeuptimers` doesn't list this task either.

I suppose Windows 10 does support wake from hibernate on RTC? My device `BIOS` certainly does, but I'm not sure what happened with this behaviour. Does configuring a wakeuptimer disable wake on hardware interrupt (like power button)? Even if this were the case, PC not waking up from hibernate at the scheduled hour is not something I was expecting...

I configured the wake up task based on my OS time. I suppose OS time and system hardware clock time are the same...?